# Leader election

Tags: system, distributed

I am reading a tutorial on distributed system. Here is a question on it and the solution it offers:

Q: Suppose we have ten nodes, each of which connects to the other nine nodes. Design a program that will run on all of them to identify a leader.

A: In the program, ask each node to wait a random amount of time, then send out a time-stamped "hello" message. The node who sends the earliest message will be the leader. If there is a tie, repeat the above procedure. This approach requires sending out 9 messages only.

Both the question and solution seem simple. My question is: is the above solution meant to say that each node will need to send 9 messages to all the other 9 nodes? Then the total number of messages sent out between the nodes will be 9 * 10 = 90. Am I right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No,

The first node sends 9 messages, every other node will receive them and won't send anything anymore, those everyone knows who is the leader.

In case another node sends out 9 "hello"-messages before it received another one, this is a tie. And every node in the system will have received those two hello messages and knowing that it is a tie. In that case only those to nodes will perform the above mentioned steps again.

Answer (score 0):

No, there does not need to be 90 total messages because once a node receives a "Hello" message it does not need to send out it's own "Hello" message as it knows there already is a master on the net.